# Only repeat request per data set row

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing

Currently I am setting up performance tests with visual studio. I have a data set containing 30 rows.

My test scenario is intended to be as follows:

- User logs in
- Visits 30 URLs defined in my data set
- User logs out

With the default functionality, the scenario does:

- User logs in
- Visits URL 1 defined in my data set
- User logs out
- User logs in
- Visits URL 2 defined in my data set
- User logs out etc.

This happens 30 times in total.

Is there a way to only repeat the step where the data rows are referred to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two approaches.

**First approach.** Have three tests. One for logging in and a second for logging out. The third test has the main activity which is to visit one URL and it will be data driven. In the load test specify the load test mix to have the login and logout tests as the initialisation and termination tests, the main test will be added to the test mix. Set the "percentage of new users" in the scenario properties to be 0%.

**Second approach.** Have just one test with the login and logout at the start and finish of this test. Between them have a loop that visits the URLs specified in the data source. Set the "advance data cursors" property of the loop to `true`.

Comment: You are my hero. The first approach worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of headache!